# What is the safest way to remove dust from electonic devices?

Tags: static-electricity

As dust inevitably settles on electronic devices such as televisions, laptops, computers and the like, what is the safest way to remove these both internally and externally?

The definition of safe includes the protection of the device as well as the person cleaning the device. For example, blowing air into a PC may an acceptable solution to rid it of dust however it may not be a suitable option from a health and safety perspective.

I am conscious that using a vacuum may not be the appropriate solution as my understanding is that it results in static electricity.

Comment: WIth the ground planes and good designs on PC MOBO's a brush with vacuum has never failed me.or a nozzle in corners

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - What do you mean by ground planes and good designs?

Comment: I meant the 8 + layer boards in modern MOBO's of OEM's like MSI

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - Interesting. I wasn't aware of these.

Answer (score 2):

There are nice little anti-static vacuums available with HEPA filters on the outlet air. A few hundreds of dollars, a pittance on the IT budget.

Product recommendations are off topic here- you can easily research them.

Edit: photo from Amazon, I got a similar product from another vendor, note the wrist straps for grounding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. While i am not seeking product recommendations, are you able to include examples of the vacuums you are referring to?

Comment: Why are wrist straps important?

Comment: You can ground yourself (through a large resistance, for safety) to limit ESD damage potentially caused by touching things when you work close to circuitry. They need to be used in conjunction with a properly configured work space and adequate training. It actually doesn't have to be fancy or expensive, but it should be done right.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the answer further with the details of ESD and examples of resistance as well as a properly configured work space? Additionally, if you can shed light on the techniques. For example, should the devices be powered off when cleaning external and internally?

Comment: @Motivated, blowing air with a lot of particles might create substantial electrostatic charge on equipment and tools. Therefore the grounding straps are there, to avoid ESD.

Comment: I think the general ESD precautions (too broad for an answer here) and the detailed manual for the vacuum, would be the best way to answer your detailed inquiry. Usually the manufacturer or distributor will allow you to download the manual before purchase.

Comment: @Ale..chenski - Does the creation of a electrostatic charge only matter if a device is powered? For example, if a computer is running and an attempt it made to clean it, an electrostatic charge is created and the device may be affected? What if the device is not plugged in?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Is there a reliable reference (aside from the manual) online i can refer to for electrostatic charge?

Comment: What is an "anti-static" vacuum anyway? I believe the only part that builds up static is the nozzle, as sucked air creates friction against the nozzle. So the only necessary change is to make the nozzle grounded to something, or make it of a material that doesn't liberate static. So it's an "anti-static" *nozzle*. The vacuum itself is standard. Just buy an anti-static nozzle and put it in your regular vacuum. Anything else seems like a scam.